# jQuery: nextSibling undefined

Tags: jquery, html

How to get `nextSibling`?

Here's my code:

```
<div>
    <p class="vend1">81125</p>
    <p class="vend2">0</p>
    <br>
</div>
```

When I do

```
$(".vend1").hover(function(){
    var vend2 = $(this).nextSibling.html();
    console.log(vend2);
});
```

it says `undefined`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `next().siblings().`

Comment: @Pekka, this shows `81125`. I need it to show `0` as in `class="vend2"`.

Comment: `nextSibling` is a DOM property, not a jQuery method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".vend1").hover(function(){
    var vend2 = $(this).next('.vend2').html();
    console.log(vend2);
});
```

Try this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/au8pys51/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".vend1").hover(function(){
    var vend2 = $(this).next().html();
    alert(vend2);
});
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/xwQGzZ)